# Animating the color of a line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm thinking about how to do a color transition for a line in WPF. I'm looking for this to be as simple and succinct as possible, and also the "correct" way in the WPF world.

This is what I have, taking the line from it's previous color to `Colors.LightGreen` in 0.1 seconds.

```
Line TargetLine = GetMyTargetLine();

var s = new Storyboard(){ Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1f)) };
s.Children.Add(new ColorAnimation(Colors.LightGreen, s.Duration));
Storyboard.SetTarget(s.Children[0], TargetLine);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(s.Children[0], new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
s.Begin();
```

And it is functional. Is this the proper way to do it in the WPF mindset? It just seems very clunky and verbose way to express what I want to do. Thoughts?

**Edit:**
With Snowbear's advice I can at least get it to 4 lines. The entire context of the storyboard is right here so I don't think it's a big deal to reference the only child by index. If it were any more complex than this I'd agree that it should be a named variable.

```
    Line TargetLine = GetMyTargetLine();        

    var story = new Storyboard() { Children = { new ColorAnimation(color, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))) } };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(story.Children[0], TargetLine);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(story.Children[0], new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
    story.Begin();
```

Comment: By the way I don't yet have the 150 rep to tag this properly so if anyone wants to step in it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

1) I believe it is not a good practice to give variables one-letter names. `Storyboard story = ...`
2) I believe you can specify `Duration` in `ColorAnimation` only. And do not set it for `Storyboard`.
3) I would introduce variable for `ColorAnimation` because `s.Children[0]` looks weird to me when I know that it is `ColorAnimation`.
4) Strangely you are using `0.1f` where parameter is double anyway.
5) I would consider using object and collection initializers for `Storyboard.Children`.
6) Optionally I would think on removing storyboard variable and start it immediatly after constructing.

Result: my code looks differently, but readability changes are subjective:

```
Line TargetLine = line;

var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(Colors.LightGreen, duration);
Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, TargetLine);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));

new Storyboard {Children = {colorAnimation}}.Begin();
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a storyboard:

```
var colourAnimation = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Red, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)));
line.Stroke.ApplyAnimationClock(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colourAnimation.CreateClock());
```